# Use dashicons in menu items?

Tags: menus

I tried to add *dashicons* to my menu items but once I save the menu, the whole item doesn't appear on my site.

I tried with:

```
<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-down"></span>
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dashicon will only available to you on admin menu images. if you want it on your menu item then you must followed option B. means using awesome font library.

for this you need to add it from this : `http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/`

i hope this will helps.